# SQL Search Query using keywords

Tags: sql, t-sql, search

I currently have a SQL query that returns results based on a dynamic number of keywords passed in.

I convert the list of keywords into a table and join to it.

```
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.udf_List2Table(@Keywords, ',') ON (Field1 LIKE '%'+Keyword+'%')
```

This is working fine but it returns all rows that contain **any** of the keywords that are suppiled. What I would like to do is return all rows that contain **all** of the keywords supplied.

I'm pretty sure you can't do this using a JOIN. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this? I'm trying to avoid dynamic SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    dbo.udf_List2Table(@Keywords, ',')
        WHERE   field1 NOT LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%'
        )
```

This can be done more efficiently if you create a `FULLTEXT` index on `field1` and make your `@Keywords` doublequote enclosed and `AND` separated:

```
SET @Keywords = '"cabbages" AND "kings"'
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   CONTAINS(Field1, @Keywords)
```

Comment: This is prone to sql injection, if you search for the keyword `''); DROP TABLE table1;--`

Comment: @Jon, I think it is simply an example using a variable and a string literal to illustrate the syntax.  In the real world i suspect @Keywords would be a parameter in a stored procedure which would not be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Jon: no, this is not, as long as you pass the Keyword in a bound parameter.

Comment: the NOT EXISTS statement returns perfect results, thanks.  I agree that a FULLTEXT index would work better but at the moment I don't have rights to create one.

@Jon, you're answer also worked well. I've opted for this approach though but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT Field1 FROM Table1
INNER JOIN
    dbo.udf_List2Table(@Keywords, ',') ON (Field1 LIKE '%'+Keyword+'%')
GROUP BY Field1
HAVING COUNT(Keyword) = n
```

to match n keywords

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do following tweak.

```
DECLARE @recordcount int
SELECT @recordcount = count(1) from dbo.udf_List2Table(@Keywords, ',')
select t1.Field1
from Table1 t1
where @recordcount = (select count(1) from dbo.udf_List2Table(@Keywords, ',') k where t1.Field1 like '%' + k.Keyword + '%')
```